# Add view to RelativeLayout with loop

Tags: xamarin

I have some strange problem with code (I put only important lines here):

```
...
RelativeLayout r;
Image[] ims
...

{ 
  r = FindByName<RelativeLayout>("relforimages"); 
  float width = 400f, height = 300f; 
  ims = new Image[2]; 

  for (int i = 0; i < 2 ; i++) { 
      ims[i] = new Image { <br>
              Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit, 
              HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
               VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
               };
      ims[i].Source = ImageSource.FromFile(localPathyn);
      ims[i].HeightRequest = 70; 
      r.Children.Add(ims[i], ()=> new Rectangle(width * i * 0.1f,  
           height * i *  0.1f, 
      70f, 70f));
      }
```

After this I see only last image in RelativeLayout. Even I increase count of images to 10 (for example) nothing happens - i see only LAST image, but if I add two or three view with the same parameters but not from array (Image[]) - everything works correctly.

Question: is it possible (in xmarin) to use array element for add view to layout dynamically? if it's possible - what is mistake i do?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using a RelativeLayout without Layout Parameter rules to place each subsequent image below the previous one.  And, without it, the images are being stacked upon each other.  It just so happens to be that your largest image is the last one placed on the screen and it obscures the other images.

Here's an example I put together using an ImageView array in Xamarin.Android with the appropriate LayoutRules to show that it works properly:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    var rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
    var iv = new ImageView[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < iv.Length; i++) {
        iv[i] = new ImageView(this);
        iv[i].SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.Icon);
        iv[i].Id = View.GenerateViewId();
        var ivParms = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        if (i == 0)
            ivParms.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignTop);      // Apply to 1st image only
        else
            ivParms.AddRule(LayoutRules.Below, iv[i-1].Id);  // This is only to be applied to the 2nd and subsequent images
        iv[i].LayoutParameters = ivParms;
        rl.AddView(iv[i]);
    }

    SetContentView(rl);
}
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is solution for Android. 
Of course if we use ImageView we have .Id field for generate unique Id for view's identification.

Different code, without LayoutParameter, but with separate variables works correct on all mobiles:

```
    Image img1, img2, img3, img4;
            img1 = new Image();
            img2 = new Image();
            img3 = new Image();
            img4 = new Image();
            setImageParm(img1, 0, localPathyn);
            setImageParm(img2, 1, localPathyn);
            setImageParm(img3, 2, localPathyn);
            setImageParm(img4, 3, localPathyn);

    void setImageParm( Image im, int i, string localPathyn) {
                im.Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit;
                im.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
                im.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
                im.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(localPathyn);
                im.HeightRequest = 70; 

                r.Children.Add(im, ()=> new Rectangle(width* i * 0.1f, height* i * 0.1f, 70f, 70f));
    }
```

I think that Children.Add method use identification by x:Name which unavailable for change in xamarin code and we have to write this code for each platform separately?